# Problems with the call to the function array_splice php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, content-management-system

I am learning PHP language a while ago and I am trying to perform some functions, **it works in a strange way**

I want to show related posts in between the text of a single post , The call to the function it work but above the text, **array_splice seems not to work**

What am I doing wrong??

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'related_inside_content' );
function related_inside_content( $content ) {
          $ads = postss(); //CALL FUNCTION!
          $p_arrayx = explode('</p>', $content );
          $p_count = 10;
          if( !empty( $p_arrayx ) ){
              array_splice( $p_arrayx, $p_count, 0, $ads );
              foreach( $p_arrayx as $key=>$value ){
                  $output .= $value;
               }
          }

      return $output;
 }
```

Function to call

```
function postss(){
$tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'customtags', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
$args = [
    'post__not_in'        => array( get_queried_object_id() ),
    'posts_per_page'      => 2,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 2,
    'orderby'             => 'relevance',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'customtags',
            'terms'    => $tags
        ]
    ]
];
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
            $my_query->the_post();
            $title =  get_the_title(); 
            $image =  get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'posts-thumb'); 
            $imagehtml = '<li>'.'<img src="'.$image . '">'.'<span class="overlayer"></span>'.'<span class="title">'. $title. '</span>'.'</li>'; 
            echo $imagehtml;
            wp_reset_postdata();
          endwhile;
 }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just add your loop `echo get_the_content()`